# Canceling a request from manager using it's cache key not working

Tags: java, android, robospice

I am trying to cancel a running request using the `SpiceManager.cancel(clazz, requestCacheKey)`, but the request is finished successfully.
The request returns a `String`, so i'm trying something like:
`spiceManager.cancel(String.class, MY_REQUEST_CACHE_KEY);`

Canceling the request directly or canceling all requests with `SpiceManager.cancelAllRequests()` works.

I first try this using a `UncachedSpiceService`, after that i used my own class extending `SpiceService`.

My question is:
**Is there a way to listen for pending request(on activity recreation) and to be able cancel the request without caching the response?**

**Answered here:**
[robospice ISSUE 251](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/issues/251)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has just been fixed and will be released in RS 1.4.13.